# Finding a summary statistic of a numeric column in a data frame based on the grouping of numeric recurring variables?

Tags: r

I have a data frame called coom.az which has 'crop fertilizer in tonnes per hectare' (Nopt) as a column in chronological order by year. In the same dataframe I have added a column which is also linked to the year column that shows the particular ENSO (phase) occuring at that time. For example;

```
Year    Nopt           phase
1950    52.5           La Nina
1951    65.2           La Nina
1952    50.0           Neutral
1953    70.9           Neutral
1954    63.4           Neutral
1955    43.3           El Nino
```

and so on

I would like to make a new vector which has calculated the median value for fertilizer within each 'phase change', for example, my first value would be the median of 52.5 and 65.2 as they both occur in the La Nina phase. The next value would be the median of 50.0, 70.9 and 63.4 as they are in the 'neutral phase', and so on.

I've tried using tidyverse code as follows:

```
#data for ENSO
phase_coom = coom.az$ONI

#data for Nopt_coom
Nopt_coom <- coom.az$Nopt_fertN_kg_ha

#creating a test dataset
medians <- data.frame(phase_coom, Nopt_coom)

library(tidyverse)
medians %>%
  group_by(phase_coom) %>% 
  summarise(median = median(Nopt_coom))

#This works to give me:

"phase   median"
La Nina  74.5           
Neutral  86.0           
El Nino  78.0
```

**Which obviously isn't what I want. I've also tried to alter this to concatenate the variable as:**

```
library(tidyverse)
medians %>%
  group_by(phase_coom,(c("La Nina","Neutral", "El Nino"))) %>% 
  summarise(medians = median(Nopt_coom)
```

**But this coding doesn't work. I am an amateur at r so at that point I was just seeing if it would work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!**

Comment: I'm confused. You want the median `Nopt` value for each `phase` grouping, correct? That's what your `tidyverse` code gives you. Also, "Which obviously isn't what I want." Perhaps post the expected output, and people here might be able to assist you better?

Comment: Hi, sorry! Yes I mean the code had the correct output for what it was meant to do, but it's not the desired thing I'm trying to achieve, which is to make a new vector which has calculated the median value for fertilizer within each phase change, as I explained in the paragraph before :) thank you! I am sorry that was confusing!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like this?

```
#Input data
df <- data.frame(Year = c(1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964), 
                  Nopt = c(52.5, 65.2, 50.0, 70.9, 63.4, 43.3, 22.1, 20.0, 84.5, 55.8, 60.0, 22.1, 30.5, 70.8, 55.2), 
                  phase = c("La Nina", "La Nina", "Neutral", "Neutral", "Neutral", "El Nino", "El Nino", "El Nino", "La Nina", "Neutral", "El Nino", "La Nina", "La Nina", "La Nina", "Neutral"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df

#    Year Nopt   phase
# 1  1950 52.5 La Nina
# 2  1951 65.2 La Nina
# 3  1952 50.0 Neutral
# 4  1953 70.9 Neutral
# 5  1954 63.4 Neutral
# 6  1955 43.3 El Nino
# 7  1956 22.1 El Nino
# 8  1957 20.0 El Nino
# 9  1958 84.5 La Nina
# 10 1959 55.8 Neutral
# 11 1960 60.0 El Nino
# 12 1961 22.1 La Nina
# 13 1962 30.5 La Nina
# 14 1963 70.8 La Nina
# 15 1964 55.2 Neutral

#tmp df to hold phases and their medians
tmpdf <- data.frame(curphase = c(), curmedian = c())

#Initialization of loop variables
i <- 1
j <- 0

#Main loop
while ( i <= nrow(df) ) {
  curphase <- df$phase[i]
  j <- i
    while ( df$phase[j] == curphase & j <= nrow(df)) {
      j <- j + 1
      }
  curmedian <- median(df$Nopt[i:(j-1)])
  i <- j
  tmpdf <- rbind(tmpdf, data.frame(curphase, curmedian))
}

tmpdf
#   curphase curmedian
# 1  La Nina     58.85
# 2  Neutral     63.40
# 3  El Nino     22.10
# 4  La Nina     84.50
# 5  Neutral     55.80
# 6  El Nino     60.00
# 7  La Nina     30.50
# 8  Neutral     55.20
```

**How this code works:**

The outer `while` loop iterates through the length of the `data frame`. Each time, it iterates, it starts at the `i`th row. The inner `while` loop conditionally finds the consecutive `j` rows which belong to the same `phase` as `i`. The median of `Nopt`s within positions `i` to `j` is then calculated, and stored along with the corresponding `phase` in `tmpdf`.

(I am plenty sure there are people who can come up with something way more efficient and elegant than this.)

Comment: Yes!! Thanks so much that's a huge help. And all good, I only need something that works!